# mkdir permission denied inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker, mkdir

I'm trying to create POST action to upload images in Django.
Using python:3.9-alpine3.13 docker image.

Dockerfile contains those lines:

```
RUN \
adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        djuser && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R djuser:djuser /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol

USER djuser
```

After this I did `docker-compose build` and tried this command:

```
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "whoami && cd ../vol/web && ls -l && mkdir ./media/uploads"
```

And got this

```
djuser
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 755      djuser        4096 Dec  5 11:07 media
drwxr-xr-x    2 755      djuser        4096 Dec  5 11:07 static
mkdir: can't create directory './media/uploads': Permission denied
```

So as I see:
I tried mkdir from django-user that have 755 permission on directory where I want to create a new directory.
Any thoughts why this doesn't work?

Creating directories using sudo and after that chmod them is not a good idea here (i think) because script must create directories. And using sudo or changing to the root everytime...

Comment: django-u != django-user

Comment: @super I read the MAN file of ls and saw that user field has 8 symbol max padding.

Comment: It's not showing the group either, so I would still be suspicious about something being wrong.

Comment: @super I edited the question by replacing django-user with djuser. Tryed that of course

Comment: How are you actually creating the container; what is in the `docker-compose.yml` file?  If you're mounting some sort of volume over `/vol`, the volume's ownership and permissions will hide any changes you make in the Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze I added a volume `dev-static-data` and mouted it to `/vol/web` inside services -> volumes `dev-static-data:/vol/web`

Comment: Right, in that case whatever ownership and permissions are in the named volume will take precedence over anything you might change in the Dockerfile.  It looks like you might have at some point `chown 755` the directory (as distinct from `chmod`) and that's now part of the volume.